# Why does the Chamberlain have an accent?

Tags: the-dark-crystal-age-of-resistance

In the series *The Dark Crystal: Age of Resistance*, each of the Skeksis have different sounds in their speech, such as a slight British accent, although most seem to have American accents, except Chamberlain. He speaks with broken English grammar.  Why?  They've been on Thra for a thousand trine, and none of the Gelflings or Skeksis have any accent or speak any other dialect.  And the Skeksis tend to speak mostly within their own kind.  Why, then, the accent?

Comment: Hmm, sorry.  Sifa elder Cadia has a thick British/Irish/Scottish accent, while no one else does.  Another anomaly here, but he does have an accent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you've watched the movie...

If you haven't this will be a spoiler..but the movie came out 30 years ago.

Anyways....The Skeksis and the urRu are actually split creatures from an immortal race of aliens called urSkeks. Weird things that we only ever see a couple of at end of the movie. When attempting to use the Crystal they ended up splitting themselves into each respective creature. Meaning the personality and existence of each is a combination or split of the original urSkek. This is the only in universe explanation of why each character is who, or rather why they are. The Chamberlain's counter part urRu likely got the better vocal chords in the deal.

Comment: Closer to 40 years ago.  *sigh*

Comment: Ok, that makes some sense.  But I noted in my question's comment that Elder Cadia also has a thick UK accent, and also, so does Gurjin and Tolyn.  All of the Gelflings, then, have same/similar accents, except Cadia, Gurjin, and Tolyn.  The urSkeks split, then, wouldn't explain their odd one-off accents.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Gurjin's father Ordon does not have an accent.  Where did Gurjin get his?

Comment: @AndrewJay Well, it's not hard to imagine people have gained specific accents from the location they're currently at. This is called Foreign accent syndrome, where natives pick up accents from a local they arn't a native of. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_accent_syndrome

The other possible thing, could be simply that they grew up most of their lives around the Skeksis, or in a different local prior to the series/movie. If I recall correctly, it was mentioned that some of the Gelfing guards only ever lived AT the castle.

Comment: Out of univerise, it's likely because those are the actors they got, unlike Ridley Scott or other directors who would painstakingly ensure things match up, Netflix and the Henson company probably think it's good enough...the audience (which is probably generally very young and some traumatised 80's kids now adults) probably don't care enough to notice. They should sound different and not particularly american...and they don't.

Comment: Well said! lol!